# What Python or CLI call can I use to terminate an AWS spot instance and request from within the spot instance itself?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, spot-instances

I have a long running aws job and am using spot instances (single-instance per job) to save money.  The python code can handle the stopping and restarting, but when I come to the end of the analysis work, I want to terminate the spot instance and not launch any more (for that batch) so that I don't have to babysit things manually (I'm using expensive GPU instances so I want to stop as soon as possible).  My code is all in python - is there an aws python sdk or cli call that will terminate that spot instance *and* stop any more from being launched, all from within the spot instance itself?  The upshot is I don't want to pay for GPU time once my work is finished.

A related question from several years ago is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289785/aws-cancel-spot-instance-request-within-a-spot-instace), but it didn't fully answer my question.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform following actions on the last spot instance:

1. Retrieve instance ID: `wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
2. Modiy the instance's shutown behavior:
   `aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior terminate`
3. Then when you want to terminate it: `sudo shutdown -h now`. Shutdown can also be scheduled by: `echo "sudo halt" | at now + 5 minutes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more Pythonic way to do this. You can use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#stopping-and-terminating-instances). It is an SDK for managing AWS instances and many services under AWS. You can use Udhav's method to get the instance id from `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` and pass this instance id to the `boto3` [function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance) to terminate it.

Please ensure while using the sdk or the cli you will have to create an IAM role with secret_access_key and secret_access_id to authenticate this request.
Below text is from official [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html)

### Programmatic access

You must provide your AWS access keys to make programmatic calls to AWS or to use
the AWS Command Line Interface or AWS Tools for PowerShell.

When you create your access keys, you create the access key ID (for example, AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE) and secret access key (for example, wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY) as a set. The secret access key is available for download only when you create it. If you don't download your secret access key or if you lose it, you must create a new one.